# Cannot use instance member 'loadJson' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available

Tags: json, swift, struct

```swift
var ToDoListData : [ToDoList] = loadJson("sample.json")
    
    func loadJson<T: Decodable>(_ filename: String) -> T {
        let data: Data
        
        guard let file = Bundle.main.url(forResource: filename, withExtension: nil)
        else {
            fatalError("\(filename) not found.")
        }
        
        do {
            data = try Data(contentsOf: file)
        } catch {
            fatalError("Could not load \(filename): \(error)")
        }
        
        do {
            return try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)
        } catch {
            fatalError("Unable to parse \(filename): \(error)")
        }
        
    }
```

I want this code to be structured.
What should I do?
Please tell me why you have to do that.

I try struct and then I get the error:

> "Cannot use instance member 'loadJson' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available"

I'd like to use this code in struct.

Comment: This issue has been covered many times before. Please review [these search results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+Cannot+use+instance+member+within+property+initializer%3B+property+initializers+run+before+%27self%27+is+available).

Comment: The code you provide is not producing this error. Where is the struct? I would also encourage you to search for "property initializers run before 'self' is available" first.